# Recursive in angular link with watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs

currently i'm doing that to make angular wait before run the scripts:

```
return {
    link: function(scope, element) {
        scope.$watch('events', function() {
            if (scope.events === undefined) {
                return;
            }

            /**
            * Every time the user access the event page, this methods
            * will be called.
            *
            */
            that.EventSidebar.init(element);
        });
    },
    restrict: 'A'
};
```

But i want to do something like this:

```
    var link = function(scope, element, first) {
        if (scope.events !== undefined && first) {
            that.EventSidebar.init(element);
            return;
        }

        scope.$watch('events', link(scope, element, true));
    }

    return {
        link: link,
        restrict: 'A'
    };
```

But my application is entering in a infinite loop, which doesn't make sense, it's the same logic, but i'm using recursion.

Cant i do that?

Thanks.

Comment: third argument of `link` is the attributes of element. What are you assuming or expecting it to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may stick to your first choice, or solve it in other way if there is a problem with it.

> But my application is entering in a infinite loop, which doesn't make
>   sense

In fact, it does. `link` function sets up a watcher that launches another `link` that sets up a watcher that launches another `link`...

As soon as `scope.events !== undefined && first` condition is false, infinite loop takes place (scope watchers make initial calls, and each `link` listener will be called at least once).

Comment: so.. is impossible use recursive?

Comment: Impossible, as long as you can't control it (and in your example you can't). Even if it was possible, recursive watchers/event listeners are no-no. Also, I don't see a reason why recursion would be desirable here.